# Maven Install - Compilation Error

Tags: maven

I'm trying to make a Maven clean/install but this is what happens when I install:

```
...
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 53 source files to C:\demoBancoWeb\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/dao/ConsignacionesDAO.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/dao/ConsignacionesDAO.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[4,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[5,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[6,32] package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[7,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[8,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[9,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[19,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class HttpServlet
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[18,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class WebServlet
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[35,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ServletConfig
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[35,55] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[49,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[49,58] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[49,95] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[61,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[61,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[61,96] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/vista/LoginView.java:[8,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/controller/OperacionesMatematicas.java:[3,30] package javax.websocket.server does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/vista/LoginView.java:[39,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpSession
  location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.vista.LoginView
[INFO] 19 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-20T21:41:51-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/143M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project demoBancoWeb: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[4,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[5,21] package javax.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[6,32] package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[7,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[8,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[9,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[19,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class HttpServlet
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[18,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class WebServlet
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[35,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ServletConfig
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[35,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ServletException
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[49,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[49,58] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[49,95] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ServletException
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[61,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[61,59] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/servlet/ControlCliente.java:[61,96] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ServletException
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.servlet.ControlCliente
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/vista/LoginView.java:[8,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/controller/OperacionesMatematicas.java:[3,30] package javax.websocket.server does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/demoBancoWeb/src/main/java/co/edu/icesi/demo/vista/LoginView.java:[39,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class HttpSession
[ERROR] location: class co.edu.icesi.demo.vista.LoginView
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have not idea what this is all about. I found that removing the .m2 folder could solve the issue but it didn't.

This is my pom:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demoBancoWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoBancoWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version> 4.1.0.RELEASE </version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version> 4.1.0.RELEASE </version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1207.jre7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its due to missing servlet-api. Include the below dependency in your pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version> //Change the version as per your needs
            <scope>provided</scope> //use provided if you are deploying war in a container
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Why? I'm importing the library and it compiles just fine. I'm using Tomcat as my server. Isn't Tomcat suppoused to fulfill this dependency?

Comment: You are right. Tomcat has this in its lib. Hence the explicit mention of provided scope. what do you mean by compile fine. is it compile from ide like eclipse? your mvn is unable to locate it and hence the missing symbols error.

Comment: Yes, compile from IDE. Hmmm so what you are saying is that Maven isn't finding the server? But it is imported in the references...

Comment: maven is unable to reference javax.servlet-api jar file that has references to the missing symbols it has complained about in the above error messages. since your war is goona be deployed in tomcat that anyways has this jar in its classpath, provided scope is sufficient here. It shall be just used for compilation and shall not bundle it with war dependencies making your war light weight. In the runtime, it shall locate from tomcat classpath

Comment: You are completely right. It doesn't detect it because the depency is inside Tomcat's scope and not Maven's, but this doesn't mean the project doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for marking my solution as the correct answer. Hope it helped you !!

Answer (score 0):

Maven is unable to find servlet-api.jar in its repository and hence cannot find dependencies while compiling. We should add dependency in Pom.xml so that maven can download required servlet-api.jar and its dependent jars.